# What are the relevant steps to deploy a model as a Unity usable version?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, unity-game-engine

Can a saved model such as this one be used with Unity?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder as pb_builder
# Save model objects - predictor and scaler object
model.save('banknote_authentication_model.h5')
# set learning phase to 0 since the model is already trained
tensorflow.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)
#load the model
pre_model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('/')
#convert h5 to protobuffer
builder = pb_builder.SavedModelBuilder('')
builder.save()
joblib.dump(sc, 'scaler.joblib')
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes a little late, but it might be useful to others:

The answer is **yes**. You can use TensorFlowSharp to load a .pb file into Unity:

- https://github.com/llSourcell/Unity_ML_Agents/blob/master/docs/Using-TensorFlow-Sharp-in-Unity-(Experimental).md

Alternatively, you can convert the model into the ONNX format and then import and use it via Unity Barracuda:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.barracuda@1.3/manual/AdvancedTopics.html

For Unity Barracuda you can also convert the model directly from the .h5 format to the ONNX format with keras2onnx:

- https://github.com/onnx/keras-onnx